# Is there a way to create an exact copy of "if" statement but with a different name?

Tags: c#

I need to create an "if" statement but with a different name. Something that I could type instead of "if" but would work exact the same way.

Comment: Why do you want this? This feels like a XY problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem .

Comment: No way. No need.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you need in pseudo code?

Comment: Maybe you can use the [Ternary Operator][1] in C#

`condition ? first_expression : second_expression;`


  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you could do this in C and C++ by use of macros.

Such a usage could have looked something like this;

```
#define FagCelDev if
```

**This is not available in C#.** According to [this source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/why-doesnt-c-support-define-macros/) this was a decision made to help keep the language readable. I would suggest that they made a good decision. There is no good reason to do what you are proposing - it will just make your code less readable.

Doing things like this is a highly effective way to confuse yourself when you read your code in a year.